# What is the meaning of Schon Rosmarin

Tags: translation

What is the meaning of Schon Rosmarin?

Comment: No context, no meaning.

Comment: Hello Carole, this forum is meant to provide answers to questions regarding German language in terms of grammar, rule, style, etc., not for translation services. Questions should demonstrate some effort on the side of the person asking. And of course, as others already pointed out, meaning is always depending on context, so you have to show the broader context of your quote. - You can rephrase your question, and it will be answered.

Answer (score 5):

I can only guess that you mean *Schön Rosmarin* and not *Schon Rosmarin*. Schön Rosmarin is the title of a composition by Fritz Kreisler, a 20 century musician from Vienna. As this is a song title, it makes barely sense to translate it, but literally *Schön Rosmarin* means something like *Lovely Rosemary*, while Rosemary refers to the spice, not to the female name.

Comment: Nice example of how omitting the dots changes the meaning.